# Use Ubuntu home server as time capsule

Tags: ubuntu, backup

I have an old dell desktop which I have installed Ubuntu 11.04 on and I have it plugged into my wireless router. I'm able to VNC into the machine using 'Chick of the VNC'. I want to use it as a Time Capsule to back up my Mac Book Pro, but when my Mac book scans for a device nothing is found.

I followed this tutorial: [*Configuring Ubuntu to Store Time Machine Backups*](http://www.pronetworks.org/forums/configuring-ubuntu-to-store-time-machine-backups-t109371-10.html) to setup the Ubuntu machine as a server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Time Machine requires an HFS+ drive to save files to, it can not function without this requirement.

I am currently using, and recommend [Super Duper](http://www.shirt-pocket.com/SuperDuper/SuperDuperDescription.html) for OS Cloning. A free alternative would be [Carbon Copy Cloner (CCC).](http://www.bombich.com/)